# How to add OR operator in Firebase Security Rules

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

```js
rules_version = '2';
firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /Users/{userId} {
    allow read: if request.auth != null;
    allow write : if itemDelete(userId);
    }
    function itemDelete(userId){
    return userId != '1.jpg' || '2.jpg' ;
    }
}
  }
```

How can I use OR || operator in firebase security rules if I use userId != '1.jpg' this works but when I use userId != '1.jpg' || '2.jpg' this not work.

Please help me

Comment: it should be correct JavaScript first, and then worry about the security rule.

Comment: 1st guess: (userId != '1.jpg') && (userId != '2.jpg')

Comment: 2nd guess: (userId != '1.jpg') || (userId != '2.jpg')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is actually an AND condition and expressed like this:

```
function itemDelete(userId){
  return (userId != '1.jpg') && (userId != '2.jpg');
}
```

Comment: I'm newbie in stack overflow so I don't know how to use it properly, still learning

Answer (score 0):

From the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage):

> `allow` rules consist of a method, such as `read` or `write`, as well
> as an (optional) condition.

In your case it means that `itemDelete(userId)` **should return a `boolean`**.

But with

```
function itemDelete(userId){
   return userId != '1.jpg' || '2.jpg' ;
}
```

it is not the case.

It's not clear to me what is the exact logic of the current code of the `itemDelete()` function so I let you adapt it in such a way it returns a `boolean` in line with your security requirements.

Comment: My problem is that I want to restrict my users to don't delete my default files define in this security rule 1.jpg and 2.jpg

Thanks for your response but my problems was solved